# how to show you save percentage in product page magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, discount, percentage

I wanted to show you save percentage in product detail page for `simple` and `configurable` both.

I have added code in `default.phtml` file location

> Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml.

```
<?php

if($_product->getTypeId() == "simple") {
   $simplePrice = $_product->getPrice();
} else {
   $_children = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product);
    foreach ($_children as $child){
    $simplePrice = $child->getPrice();
    break;
   }
}

$_finalPrice =$_product->getFinalPrice();
$_price = $simplePrice;
if($_finalPrice < $_price) {
   $_savingPercent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice / $_price)*100);
   **echo 'Your save '.$_savingPercent . '%';**

}
?>
```

Comment: Is it working for you or please ask your question

Comment: Specify the issue you are facing into details?